# getExternalFilesDir NOT creating new Directory

Tags: android, file, directory, directory-structure

I am trying to CHECK to see if a Subdirectory Structure on the SD Card Exists;
If NOT then CREATE a new one.
That is of course AFTER my code verified that the SD Card is mounted and ready.

I created code that WORKED, and I successfully created the structure ON MY CELL PHONE'S SD Card, so I know my code was good.  I then went to bed.  The next day, I MOVED the working code from my TEST area to my WORKING area and now it won’t work!!  :-(  I even MOVED it Back to the test area and Still no workie!!

I'm guessing that at night the Android Gremlins did something to break the code!!

So...either the Android Gremlins did something OR perhaps (and this is a long shot) I might have forgotten something when I moved the code.   Does anybody have any Gremlin repellent??

I’m pretty sure the code that WORKED and actually created the structure that I CAN NOW SEE on my phone was something like this:

---

```
String strPathName = m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) .toString ();
// This DOES give the Correct Path on the SD Card

File dir;  

dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/MyDirectory");  
dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/MyDirectory/SubDir");  
dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/MyDirectory/SubDir/xxx");
```

On my Cell Phone, I can clearly see this structure.  It is still there now!!

The next day, (i.e. AFTER a visit from the Android Gremlins) I attempted to MOVE this and other code FROM my Test area to a different section and after that, it no longer would CREATE a structure.

### I step thru with the De-Bugger (i.e. Gremlin Killer) and here is what happens.

```
File dir;  
boolean bDirExists;  

dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/NewDirectory");  
bDirExists = (dir.exists () && dir.isDirectory () );  // FALSE  

dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/NewDirectory/SubDir");  
bDirExists = (dir.exists () && dir.isDirectory () );   // FALSE  
bDirExists = dir.exists ();                                                     // FALSE  
bDirExists = dir.isDirectory ();                                            // FALSE  

dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/NewDirectory/SubDir/xxx");  
bDirExists = (dir.exists () && dir.isDirectory () );   // FALSE
```

IF…. I use the original name that I used the previous day "/MyDirectory/SubDir/xxx")
THEN the code indicates that the Directory DOES EXIST

```
dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/MyDirectory");  
bDirExists = (dir.exists () && dir.isDirectory () );   // TRUE  

dir = new File (m_Context.getExternalFilesDir (null) + "/MyDirectory/SubDir");  
bDirExists = (dir.exists () && dir.isDirectory () );   // TRUE  
bDirExists = dir.exists ();   // TRUE  
bDirExists = dir.isDirectory ();   // TRUE
```

Now… as we ALL KNOW, programmers NEVER break their code and NEVER introduce errors into “known to be working code” so…. It MUST be Gremlins…. Right??

---

### First Update

@ChuongPham commented that I may need to add the correct Permission in the Manifest file.

Since the code DID WORK, it means that I DID already enable this permission.
However, I decided to REMOVE this permission and see what ERROR it would throw, I thought it would not compile without the permission.  I then ran the code and NO ERROR was thrown!!  And YES, it still will NOT create a new file..

Comment: Your objective, when writing a question on StackOverflow, should be to make it as easy as possible for those in position to help to actually help. The EXTRANEOUS SHOUTING, references to fictional creatures, and the redundant punctuation all combine to make this question much harder to understand than it needs to be.

Answer (score 9):

If you use `m_Context.getExternalFilesDir("MyDirectory/SubDir")` the custom directory is created automatically for you. Tested on API 19 or greater...

Comment: Confirmed to work on Android 10, they should update the inline docs to make it clear. That should be be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple to create custom directory. Please check the below code:

```
File folder = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Your directory name");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        File filename = new File(folder, "Your file name");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
```

Comment: Note: This code will work like charm in API level 29 as Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated, this is the best alternate solution.

Comment: i tried this code, its not working for me in Samsung a70 android 10. directory is not created when using this code. getExternalStorageDirectory() is working but it is deprecated..any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Also, read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) for caveats regarding API 19 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the GUESS...  But As I said.. It ALREADY WORKED.... and created files on the SD Card.... so YES... I already included android.permission.RITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.  I didn't think I needed to include that in the ORIGINAL problem statement since I indicated that It DID work...  But it IS THERE in the Manefest

Comment: Well, the more info you provided, the easier it is for us to know what issues you are having with your Android development so we can help you. One thing I would try is debug your variable `m_Context` to see if it's returning null or not. That's the first thing I would check.

Comment: You do not need to add this permission for `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 0):

you must call `dir.mkdirs()` to create directories!!!

Comment: but I call dir.mkdirs(), It still does not exist